# The style of website is different on iOS devices

Tags: html, css, frontend

For example this input of type submit.. 
windows and android: http://s24.postimg.org/ia239b9ch/Untitled.png

iOS: http://s17.postimg.org/4y4nuc8qz/test.jpg

Same result with various types of browsers on iOS (Google, Chrome, and safari) 

`<input class="blueSubmit" type="submit" value="test">`

```
<style>
.blueSubmit {
background-color: #64B5F6;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 3px 2%;
border-radius: 5px;
font-size: 110%;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;
border: 0;
}
.blueSubmit:hover, .blueSubmit:focus {
background-color: #1E88E5;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every browser has its own default CSS-values. To get the same look in iOS, use `-webkit-appearance: none;` in the CSS of your input-field.

```
.blueSubmit {
    background-color: #64B5F6;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 3px 2%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 110%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Should work!

Comment: I think its the only practice to do that. It's just the same as resetting the margin or anything else; you just reset the default options from browser to style it for yourself. And yes, you could use the `-webkit-appearance: none;` to every element (`* { -webkit-appearance: none; }`).